# Rename files "The syntax of the command is incorrect" .bat

Tags: batch-file, file-rename

I am trying to remove a string from multiple file names in multiple directories. This is the file as with a few files being created so that I can check what values are actually being SET.

When I  get to the `rename` at the very bottom I get an error:

> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

I don't see anything amiss in the `_intf` and `_fnlf` text files that get created. Is there some trick to using variables as the file path in a rename?

```
@ECHO off

echo Delete dir.txt?
PAUSE

del dir.txt
del item.txt
del file.txt

::paths for all directories in root (where filerename.bat is run)
 ::get root dir path
 SET "_c=%CD%"
 SET /A "counter=0"
 ::get dir list and concats root dir path before
 FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A in ('DIR /on /b /a:d /p %svnLOCAL%') DO ( 
    SET "_dirp=%_c%\%%A"
    CALL :sub1
    SET /A "_counter+=1"
 )

::finds each file in dir
:sub1
 ::make file to check dir path
 ECHO "%_dirp%" > dir.txt
 FOR /F "tokens=*" %%B in ('DIR /b %_dirp%') DO (
  ECHO "%%B" > item.txt
  SET "_item=%%B"
  SET "_filep=%_dirp%\"
  CALL :sub2 %%~nB
PAUSE
 )
 ECHO "%_counter%"
EXIT /b 0

::builds file paths
:sub2
 set "str=%*"
 set "str=%str:[1]=%"
 SET "_intf=%_filep%%_item%"
 SET "_fnlf=%_filep%%str%"
 CALL :sub3
EXIT /b 0

::Renames each file
:sub3
 ECHO "%_intf%" > _intf.txt
 ECHO "%_fnlf%" > _fnlf.txt
 ren "%_intf%" "%_fnlf%.jpg"
EXIT /b 0
```

Comment: Tracing `%_fnlf%` back to `%_filep%` which is set with value of `%_dirp%\ `. The 2nd argument of `ren` is a filename only, yet you have a backslash, which will make the argument invalid. See `ren /?`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your error is because you're not using the `REName` command correctly.

This can be noted by entering `Ren /?` at the Command Prompt, which shows the syntax as:

```
REN [drive:][path]filename1 filename2
```

You however seem to be using:

```
REN [drive:][path]filename1 [drive:][path]filename2
```

…which will produce the error:

> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

As a simple fix for your script, you'd need to change the following line:

```
set "str=%str:[1]=%"
```

to:

```
set "_fnlf=%str:[1]=%"
```

Then remove the line:

```
SET "_fnlf=%_filep%%str%"
```

---

If you wanted to tidy the code up you could probably change it to:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "i=0"
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B/AD "%svnLOCAL%" 2^>Nul') Do (
    Set /A i+=1
    For /F "Delims=" %%B In ('Dir /B/A-D "%~dp0%%A\*[1]*" 2^>Nul') Do (
        Set "$=%%~nB"
        Call Ren "%~dp0%%A\%%B" "%%$:[1]=%%.jpg"
    )
)
Echo "%i%"
Pause
```

Or Using DelayedExpansion:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "i=0"
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B/AD "%svnLOCAL%" 2^>Nul') Do (
    Set /A i+=1
    For /F "Delims=" %%B In ('Dir /B/A-D "%~dp0%%A\*[1]*" 2^>Nul') Do (
        Set "$=%%~nB"
        SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        Ren "%~dp0%%A\%%B" "!$:[1]=!.jpg"
        EndLocal
    )
)
Echo "%i%"
Pause
```

---

In the two examples above, I've taken your comment, `where filerename.bat is run`, to mean the directory in which this script, `filerename.bat`, is located. If you meant the current working directory, *which is not necessarily the same*, you should replace the instances of `%~dp0` above with `%__CD__%`.

Additionally, *as is not clear from the information you've provided*, I have assumed that `%svnLOCAL%` has already been defined.

Comment: Thank you Compo. I changed my original file, per your suggestion, to fit the needed syntax of the command and it work great. I pulled a bit of code from another post here which is where that '%svnLOCAL%' came from. It worked for some reason but I just changed it to '%CD%' and it functions the same as far as I can tell - am I missing something on how the 'DIR' works?